# how to transpose every multiple rows that start with a specific string into columns?

Tags: python, dataframe, reshape, transpose

I would like to ask how to transpose every multiple rows into columns and save into text file using python? I have attached input and expected output at the following part. According to the input, I would like to select every rows that starts with 'number' and then transpose into columns.

Finally i would like to save expected output into text file.

input:

```
number 
12
apple
13
banana
14
number
1
carrot
2
cucumber
3
number 
11
pen
10
```

expected output:

```
number    12     apple     13     banana       14
number    1      carrot    2      cucumber     3
number    11     pen       10
```

Any help will be appreciated., thanks!

Comment: sorry for the input that i typed, the way of the presentation of the input is what i tried to do, i am not sure why it is like that, please take a look on the images that i uploaded to google drive, thanks a lot!!

Comment: What is the type of the expected output file ?

Comment: hi, sir, the expected output file is in .txt format (text file format)

Comment: it is cool as well if the expected output file is in .xlsx or .csv format (excel file format).

Comment: thanks a lot to Alexandre B. for correcting my question, sorry for my improper way of my question as this is my first time to get into this stack overflow.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I tried to convert input file (text file) into excel file, I managed to convert it but I stuck afterward, I don't know how to find out the row with specific word 'number' and transpose the following rows into columns.

Comment: This seems like a homework question. Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) under "Asking about homework"

Comment: ok, thanks for the your reminds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other questions exist about reading and writing text files, so I'll leave those bits to you as an exercise.

Say you already have your input file loaded in as `records`:

```
records = ['number', '12', 'apple', '13', 'banana', '14', 'number', '1', 'carrot', '2', 'cucumber', '3', 'number', '11', 'pen', '10']
```

What you want to do is loop over each `record`, and if it's `'number'`, create a new row, then add the `record` to the most recent row. This code does that:

```
rows = []
for record in records:
    if record == 'number':
        # Create a new row
        rows.append([])
    # Append to the last row
    rows[-1].append(record)
```

`rows` will then be this:

```
[['number', '12', 'apple', '13', 'banana', '14'],
 ['number', '1', 'carrot', '2', 'cucumber', '3'],
 ['number', '11', 'pen', '10']]
```

Comment: @EdisonToh Great, happy to help! If you found my answer the most useful, please tick the checkbox on the left, which marks it as "accepted" and effectively marks your question as "answered".

Comment: really appreciate your help!! Is that any other way to give you credit besides tick the checkbox on the left? Is it the checkbox on left of your answer referring to a 'tick'? If that so, I had clicked it.

Comment: @EdisonToh Yeah, you can upvote any answers you found useful, by clicking the up-arrow on the left. And yes, you found the "accept" button correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First let's load the data into memory:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as data:
    info = data.read()
info = info.split()
```

Now let's pair the data into `(name, number)` tuples:

```
list_of_tuples = [(name, int(info[index+1])) for name, index in enumerate(info)]
```

Now find your rows:

```
list_of_rows = []
cur_row = []
for tuple in list_of_tuples:
    if tuple[0] == 'number':
         if len(cur_row) > 0:
              list_of_rows.append(cur_row)
              cur_row.clear()
         cur_row.append(tuple)
list_of_rows.append(cur_row)
```

Now load it into a text file:

```
with open('out.txt', 'w') as out:
     for row in list_of_rows:
          out.write('\t'.join(row))
```

Code was mind-compiled, so let me know if you run into problems...

Comment: You have `enumerate` backwards - it returns `index, value` tuples. And I haven't tested this myself, but it seems like it will produce duplicates; I think you want `enumerate(info[::2])`

Comment: Hi, cuniculus, I've ran your codes, but it seems like ran into some other problems, here is the error:

```
list_of_tuples = [(name, int(info[index+1])) for name, index in enumerate(info)]
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```
I still can't figure out the error..

Comment: ok, wjandrea, I will try on your suggestion, thanks. By the way, how would you guys put the code/data onto a light grey box? I've tried it but no luck for me...

Comment: @EdisonToh Actually I'm trying my suggestions now but can't get it to work. I'll add another comment shortly. For the grey box, see [Code and Preformatted Text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) on the Markdown Help page

Comment: So I changed `list_of_tuples = [(name, int(info[index+1])) for index, name in enumerate(info) if not name.isdigit()]`, but `list_of_rows` is then `[[('number', 11)], [('number', 11)], [('number', 11)]]`.

Comment: hi, wjandrea, thanks for your help, I will try it later. I will also take a look on the 'code and preformatted text', by the way, how to give you all like or credit to your help? I would like to give credit to you and cuniculus.

Comment: hi, cuniculus, thanks your help too!! Is that a way to give credit on your help?

Comment: Hi @EdisonToh, glad if this was helpful. It's good practice to include a link to non-trivial code that's copied directly from StackOverflow, but I wouldn't worry about it otherwise.

Comment: Hi @cuniculus, ok and thanks for your help, really appreciate!